# C++ Vector iterators incompatible, but iterators seem to be valid to me

Tags: c++, object, vector, iterator

first post here, it is the first time I need to ask a question myself: I've searched for the answer but I couldn't find it.

I get the error "`Expression: vector iterators incompatible`" in debug mode with Visual Studio 2013. The usual reason for this error is that in a for, the iterators do not point to the same  object, or the end iterator gets invalid because of a reallocation during the loop, but here I don't see anything like that...

The error occurs in the copy constructor of my LogicFormula class:

```
struct LogicFormula {
  id_t ID;
  type_t type_formula;
  operator_t type_operator;
  bool bool_value;
  std::string name;
  ListOfConstants *list_of_constants;
  std::vector<LogicFormula*> children;

  LogicFormula(const LogicFormula &original) {
    type_formula = original.type_formula;
    type_operator = original.type_operator;
    bool_value = original.bool_value;
    name = original.name;
    for (std::vector<LogicFormula*>::const_iterator it =
      original.children.cbegin(); it != original.children.cend(); ++it)
      children.push_back(new LogicFormula(**it));
    if (original.list_of_constants)
      list_of_constants = new ListOfConstants(*(original.list_of_constants));
    else
      list_of_constants = NULL;
  }

  LogicFormula(bool value) {
    type_formula = PROPOSITIONAL_CONSTANT;
    type_operator = LEAF;
    bool_value = value;
    list_of_constants = NULL;
  }

  // [...]
};
```

The error is detected at the line:

```
for (std::vector<LogicFormula*>::const_iterator it =
  original.children.cbegin(); it != original.children.cend(); ++it)
```

I made a minimal main function that raises the error:

```
int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    LogicFormula a(true);
    a = testLogic();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope I gave you everything, and sorry if my english is bad: I'm french.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to give the function testLogic:

```
LogicFormula testLogic(void) {
    LogicFormula f(true);
    return f;
}
```

The call to the copy constructor is then made by the `return f;`

Just for information, `id_t`, `type_t`, `operator_t` are enumerated types (declared with enum in the class LogicFormula), capital character things are just constants of these types (that work fine in the rest of the program) and `ListOfConstants` is another class, but I don't think this is important, actually in this test the vector original.children is empty and `original.list_of_constraints` is NULL...
And the error is a runtime error, it compiles just fine...

Comment: Why don't you use the initialiser list and let the copy-constructor take care of it? Anyway, you use far too much dynamic allocation.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @chardetm - you did *not* give us everything.  What is `id_t`, `operator_t`. `type_t`, `ListOfConstants`, `PROPOSITIONAL_CONSTANT`, `LEAF`, etc.?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Just use `int` for the types. They seem to be tangential to any issue the OP has. Trouble is, there's no error then.

Comment: Is this a compilation error or a runtime error?

Comment: post the code of `testLogic()`

Comment: Edited: see the EDIT in my post, thanks for your answers!

Comment: @Deduplicator: Re:copy-ctr, he's seems to be doing a deep copy, the `std::vector` copy-ctr would just copy the pointers.

Comment: @Deduplicator as @BenjaminBannier said, I need to copy the children of the formula (this actually represents a tree structure for logic formulas with and, or, there exists, for all, implies, and so on) and I need to have a vector of pointers of `LogicFormula` for children instead of a vector of `LogicFormula` because I have algorithms to change the structure of the tree (to factor or expand formulas, etc...) so manipulating pointers is much more easier, or at least much more optimized...

Comment: @RakibulHasan: posted, sorry I had forgotten to put this...

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code (excluding some variables like `id`,`type_formula`) without any problem. Are you sure the code in `main` is all you have?

The problem may be in this line:

```
 a = testLogic();
```

Note that it is `assignment` not `copy`. So the statement will use compiler generated `operator=` for class `LogicFormula` instead of using the `copy constructor`. The default `operator=` will bit-wise copy the `list_of_constants` and `children` instead of looping through the container. The `f` in `testLogic` will be destroyed, so will be the `list_of_constants` and `children`. So after assignment `a` will have invalid members.

Another problem may be you are not initializing `children` in the constructor. The return value of `testLogic` will be copied using the `copy constructor` in which it will try to access `children`.